# Don't Pre-populate Examples in Swagger UI Try it Out Feature

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

Is it possible to disable pre-populating examples from the spec for OAS 3.0 in Swagger UI?

I have a GET request that allows filtering by *many* different parameters. When the user clicks 'Try it out' ALL the parameters are pre-populated. There are never any results, due the the sheer number of filtering options selected.

If the user wants to make any meaningful request, they must first go in and remove *every single* example.

This seems to have been the default for Swagger 2.0, but OAS 3.0 does not seem to have an option.

I've tried changing various [settings](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#user-content-supportedsubmitmethods) without success.

The only thing that works is changing the definition from OAS 3.0 to Swagger 2.0. But this obviously isn't a workable solution.

**When the spec is defined as OAS 3.0:**

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "paths": {...}
}
```

[image: Swagger UI defaults to autofill all the examples in Try it Out]

**When the spec is defined as Swagger 2.0:**

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "paths": {...}
}
```

[image: Swagger UI defaults to leave all the examples blank]

Notes:

- The rest of the spec and all settings remain unchanged in the examples above.

Comment: Have you tried the [`parameterMacro`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#macros) config to clear the default values?

Comment: @Helen Thanks for the suggestion, I had not, but I just tried it and it did not produce the desired result.

It looks like that macro allows me to adjust the example or default values, but they remain pre-populated as soon as I click the Try It Out button