How to programatically set field values in Swagger UI
I'm using Rswag and Swagger UI, and I have two inputs on my form that I want to load dynamically from server side data, called date_range_start and date_range_end.  The values I want to set are based on the current date and the timezone of the user, so I don't want to put them directly as examples in the openapi spec, but instead fetch them server side and update the form on load.
I have the same question as was asked here.  I'm reasking it because I don't think the approach discussed there is likely to be the right way to do this.  The approach they're taking seems to be hacky, directly manipulating the DOM, instead of using Swagger UI functions.  Is there a way within SwaggerUI to set fields on load?
I would probably put it inside this where you see the comment:
configObject.onComplete = {
  // set specific form input values based on fetch
}
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle(configObject);

I don't need help with the fetch part of it, just trying to understand how you can set parameter form values programmatically in swagger ui.

I found that I could adapt this approach, and set default values in particular cases.  Note that dispatchInitialValue=false allows you to actually clear out any examples from the input; on my version of Swagger it doesn't send those examples by default like you see claimed in the linked post.
const SetDefaultParamsPlugin = () => ({
  wrapComponents: {
    JsonSchemaForm: (Original, { React }) => ({ value, description, ...props }) => {
      let dispatchInitialValue = true;
      if (description == "date_range_start") {
        value = defaultRangeStart;
      } else if (description == "date_range_end") {
        value = defaultRangeEnd;
      } else {
        dispatchInitialValue = false;
      }

      return React.createElement(Original, { ...props, value, description: value, dispatchInitialValue })
    }
  },
});

configObject.plugins = [SetDefaultParamsPlugin];


Swagger UI has the parameterMacro config that let you dynamically set example values for operation parameters. parameterMacro is a function that accepts two arguments - operation object and parameter object - and returns the example value for the input operation and parameter. Within the function you can check the operation's operationId and the parameter's name to target only specific parameters.
Here's an example of using parameterMacro in standalone Swagger UI:
  // swagger-initializer.js

  window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.json",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    ...

    parameterMacro: function (operation, parameter) {
      if (operation.operationId === "getPetById" && parameter.name === "petId") {
        return 12345;
      }
    }
  });


Since you're using Rswag rather than standalone Swagger UI, check if exposes the parameterMacro config or provides a way to customize the SwaggerUIBundle initialization code.

This just changed default value for the field, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330421/dont-pre-populate-examples-in-swagger-ui-try-it-out-feature#comment131229871_74330421. It says "Default value: 12345" as if I set default in the spec. it does not change input.

Interesting... In the standalone version (v. 5.17.14) this both appends "default value: ..." to the description AND changes the input: https://i.sstatic.net/tCffftky.png

If you replace return 12345; with parameter.example = 12345; (if you use OpenAPI 3.x) or parameter["x-example"] = 12345; (for OpenAPI 2.0), does it work? The doc says the parameter argument is immutable but it actually seems to be mutable.

I have an approach that seems like it will work based on what's done here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5776#issuecomment-2002044342 .  Setting value allows me to programatically control the defaults.  Will post approach I took in a bit.
Note that rswag is using an earlier version of swagger-ui and everything else (will have to check)

Scratch that, the whole approach just breaks my swagger-ui ^^. Going to try your approach with mutability.  Example would seem to get what I want, let's see

With some modifications I was actually able to make the linked approach work, curious your thoughts @Helen.

@BenG I haven't used JsonSchemaForm override myself but if that's what works for you - great! And thanks for sharing your solution.

The solution has some issues so I'm trying to come up with a better one now (unchecked my answer).  Fyi the issue with just using parameterMacro is it will set the default, but example(s) take higher precedence in initially filling in the JsonSchemaForm.  See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/components/parameter-row.jsx#L122
The approach I'm exploring right now is whether I could just dispatch the default values after the page has loaded.

What I'm looking at now is whether I could just use a plugin to replace ParameterRow with a component that has a different setDefaultValue https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/components/parameter-row.jsx#L96

@BenG I wonder if it will be easier to dynamically patch the OpenAPI spec itself upon load (using Swagger UI's oncomplete handler) and insert the needed example values? There's an example here of how to patch the servers list, you could try a similar approach for parameters. For the reference, ui.specSelectors.specJson() returns an Immutable.js Map.

what patch could be made to the spec that would accomplish the desired result?  Because we still want to keep examples, but they will be the defaults as long as they're in the spec.

I actually ended up modifying the spec for the API by moving all the examples to the descriptions.  I consider this a failing of swagger ui, like everyone on the github thread I linked.  However by not using examples I can have it only use defaults for prefills.
For setting specific fields programmatically my approach is to replace ParameterRow which is one level higher than JsonSchemaForm.  I will post this combined approach.
Swagger UI would benefit from separating prefill values from examples.
